Interpretation of the one-sided t-test
I am comparing two methods, called A and B, on their performance (the lower the error, the better)
I have a set of inputs, and I ran both methods for each input, logging the errors. A consistently produces lower errors than B.
I then perform the one-sided two-sample t-test on A and B:
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(A_errors, B_errors, alternative='less', equal_var=False)
which gives a large negative statistic and a small p-value (lower than 0.05).
Does this mean I can conclude that it is statistically significant that A improves over B?

Are you measuring the error signed or as absolute values? If the latter, how are you justifying a $t$-test?

Yes, it does. The $p$-value is the probability that you are being fooled by random fluctuations; the smaller it gets, the more assurance that you are looking at something real.
